# How to make a slick slider continuously autoplay, but speed up scroll on arrow/dot click?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, carousel, slick.js

I would like to make a slider, which is continuously autoplay. It works fine, but the arrows and dots don't look to work properly. I'm not sure which of the settings should I change, but I would like the slider to instantly scroll after clicking on the arrow or dot.

I was trying to change some settings with the code below, but nothing seems to work fine.

When `speed` is set to `6000` autoplay has perfect timing, but the same slow speed is used on scrolling after clicking on the dot/arrow and this behavior is unwanted (it should scroll immediately to chosen slide). Could you please help me to understand what should I do to achieve my goal?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.test').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1,
    speed: 6000,
    dots: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    waitForAnimate: false,
    pauseOnFocus: false, 
    pauseOnHover: false
  });
});
```

```css
.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before 
{
    color: black!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick-theme.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<div style='margin-left:20px;width:200px;color:black!important;'>
    <div class='test'>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some JS options may not work with another setting (as it does in SwiperJS) so as you go through each added JS function watch for it to potentially negate another earlier setting.
The following should get you on track (as an example).

```
<section class="slider">
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.gif/?text=1">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 800,
  pauseOnFocus: false, 
  pauseOnHover: true
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean? All links work fine...

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the transition speed on arrow/dot click by updating the speed property in the slick function. Here is an example in jQuery:

```js
$('.your-slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 6000,
  speed: 1000,
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
});

$('.slick-arrow').on('click', function() {
  $('.your-slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'speed', 1000, true);
});

$('.slick-dots button').on('click', function() {
  $('.your-slider').slick('slickSetOption', 'speed', 1000, true);
});
```

This code sets the autoplay speed to 6000ms, but when the arrow or dot is clicked, it changes the transition speed to 1000ms. You can adjust the speed value to your desired transition speed on arrow/dot click.

Comment: As I commented above, it stops the slider for 6 seconds and my question refers to continuous autoplay without any breaks